# Checking whether elements of an Array contains a specified String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I am working on an iOS app. I have an array,

```
NSArray *qwer=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apple Juice",@"Apple cake",@"Apple chips",@"Apple wassail"nil];
for(int k=0; k<qwer.count; k++) {
    //
}
```

I am trying to check whether my array contains string '**wassail**'. Can anyone help me to find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSString` has a `rangeOfString` function that can be used for looking up partial string matches. This function returns `NSRange`. You can use the `location` property.

```
...
  NSArray *qwer = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apple Juice",@"Apple cake",@"Apple chips",@"Apple wassail"nil];
    for (NSString *name in qwer){
      if ([name rangeOfString:keyword].location == NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"contains");
      } 
    }
...
```

Reference :

1. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1416849-rangeofstring
2. https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsrange

Thanks
Sriram

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
NSArray *qwer=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Apple Juice",@"Apple cake",@"Apple chips",@"Apple wassail",nil];
for(int k=0; k<qwer.count; k++) {
    NSString *currentString =[qwer objectAtIndex:k];
    if ([currentString rangeOfString:@"wassail"].location == NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"string does not contain wassail");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"string contains wassail!");

        break;
    }
}
```